# Swift protocol extension self reference issues with init

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I'm looking for a way to add a default initializer to a protocol via protocol extensions.

My protocol is:

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    var myVar : Double { get set }
    init(value: Double)
    init(existingStruct : TestProtocol)
}
```

I've implemented a struct using this protocol as:

```
struct TestStruct : TestProtocol {
    var myVar : Double

    init(value : Double) {
        myVar = value
    }

    init (existingStruct : TestProtocol) {
        myVar = existingStruct.myVar
    }
}
```

However if I try via **extension** to make a default initializer for this protocol I run into self issues:

```
extension TestProtocol {
    init(value : Double) {
        myVar = value
    }

    init(existingStruct : TestProtocol) {
        myVar = existingStruct.myVar
    }
}
```

Where both assignment lines issue the error 
**Variable 'self' passed by reference before being initialized**

Is there a way to make this work - or am i limited to using classes?

[image]

Comment: Is that xcode with the monokai theme? I want it! <3

Comment: https://github.com/b0ti/xcode-monokai-revisited

Comment: Ups, how can you guarantee that concrete type adopting `TestProtocol` will be completely initialised by the `init`s in the protocol extension? especially for value types (i.e.: structs or enums).

Comment: @MatteoPiombo nothing is impossible :) I'll post the solution as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your question is almost the same as in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31302978/4572536) I answered yesterday.

Here is the trick to solve this :)

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    var myVar : Double { get set }
    init() // designated initializer which will ensure that your class or structer type will instantiate correctly
}

struct TestStruct : TestProtocol {
    var myVar : Double

    init() {
        myVar = 0
    }
}

extension TestProtocol {
    init(value : Double) {
        self.init()
        myVar = value
    }

    init(existingStruct : TestProtocol) {
        self.init()
        myVar = existingStruct.myVar
    }
}
```

Have a good day. :) Protocol extension is so nice.