# Limits of Protocol Extensions and defaults in swift2

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols

So I was playing around with protocol extensions and i ran into an "interesting" problem.

I wanted to write a `Meters` and `Kilometers` units type for testing some things out.  Its VERY easy to do this as a class where there is a base class and both sub classes override the base, while just overriding a simple value

```
//Conversion factor between types
enum DISTANCE_UNIT_TYPE : Double {

    case METER = 1.0;
    case KILOMETER = 0.001;
}

protocol DistanceUnit {

    var unitType : DISTANCE_UNIT_TYPE {get}
    var value : Double { get set }
    var baseValue : Double { get set }
}


struct Kilometers : DistanceUnit {

    var unitType = DISTANCE_UNIT_TYPE.KILOMETER
    var value : Double
    var baseValue : Double

    init(_ v : Double) {
        value = v
        baseValue = v * unitType.rawValue
    }
}


struct Meters : DistanceUnit {

    var unitType = DISTANCE_UNIT_TYPE.METER
    var value : Double
    var baseValue : Double

    init(_ v : Double) {
        value = v
        baseValue = v * unitType.rawValue
    }
}
```

So as you can see i have lots of duplicate code (specifically the initializers)

I tried to make a protocol extension to set the default initializer

```
extension DistanceUnit {

    init(_ v : Double) {
        value = v
        baseValue = v * unitType.rawValue
    }
}
```

but I get an error of **variable 'self' passed by reference before being initalized**

Is there any way to get this to work or do i just have to type lots of duplicate code?  Maybe using `unsafe` or something?

Comment: this might be reaching... but I think we may be able to find justification for how this works in the following -> "[p]rotocols can be extended to provide method and property implementations to conforming types" -- however, initializers are not "methods", the programming language guide tells us that "initializers... are like special methods" -> so perhaps we can take from this that we aren't meant to be able to provide default implementations for initializers using a protocol extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that `fqdn` is right and we won't be able to use custom inits inside protocols extension as we would like to, but only time will tell.

But there is still some workaround:

```
struct Meters : DistanceUnit {

    var unitType = DISTANCE_UNIT_TYPE.METER
    var value : Double
    var baseValue : Double

    init() { // this one is needed as designated initializer for your protocol extension
        value = 0
        baseValue = 0
    }
}

protocol DistanceUnit {

    var unitType : DISTANCE_UNIT_TYPE {get}
    var value : Double { get set }
    var baseValue : Double { get set }
    init() // this is new and you will NEED to implement this in your structure or class
}

extension DistanceUnit {

    init(_ v : Double) {
       self.init()
       value = v
       baseValue = v * unitType.rawValue
    }

    // you can now implement a lot more different default inits and they should work fine here :)
    // here is a quick example

    init(_ s : String) {
       self.init(Double(s.characters.count))
    }
}
```

Hope that will help you. I learned this trick a few days ago when i was building a custom generic singleton generator with protocol extensions ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31270708/4572536)).